# Analizando expresiones aritméticas utilizando PILAS

Tags: java, poo, lista, pilas

Ejercicio: Elaborar un programa tal que analize si una expresion aritmética esta dada de manera correcta o incorrecta. Ejemplo: `input: (4+(3-5))/7 output: es correcto` y si `input: (4+)3-5))/7, output: es incorrecto`.
Ya hice el programa, pero por alguna razón, siempre da como output:
`"La expresión está escrita de manera correcta"` y ésto es porque la `pila4` siempre queda vacía, y no entiendo porqué sucede, la pila4 **no** debe de estar vacía (para el contraejemplo de abajo).

Este es el **contraejemplo** que tengo: `input: ((t` y da como `output:`"La expresión esta escrita de manera correcta"`.

```
public class Tarea5sep {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("De que tamaño sera su expresion?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    LinkedList pila = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila3 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila4 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList pila5 = new LinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca su elemento");
        String e = x.nextLine();
        pila.push(e);
        pila2.push(e);
        pila3.push(e);
        x.nextLine();
    }
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if (pila.pop().equals(")")) {
            String sim = (String) pila.pop();
            if (0 == sim.compareTo("+") || 0 == sim.compareTo("-") || 0 == sim.compareTo("*") || 0 == sim.compareTo("/")) {
                a++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (a != 0) {
        System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta");
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String simbolo = (String) pila2.pop();
            if (0 == simbolo.compareTo("+") || 0 == 
      simbolo.compareTo("-") || 0 == simbolo.compareTo("*") || 0 == 
  simbolo.compareTo("/")) {
                if (pila2.pop().equals(")")) {
                    b++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (b != 0) {
            System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de manera correcta");
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                String elemento = (String) pila3.pop();
                if (0 == elemento.compareTo("(")) {
                    pila4.push("(");
                } else {
                    pila5.push(elemento);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < pila5.size(); i++) {
                String paren = (String) pila5.pop();
                if (0 == paren.compareTo(")")) {
                    pila4.pop();
                }

            } //si input: ( ( t, entonces pila4 tiene: ( ( y por tanto 
       //no debe se estar vacia. 
            System.out.println("contenido de pila4" + pila4);//Y dice 
     //que pila4 tiene 0 elementos

            if (pila4.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("La expresion esta escrita de manera 
      correcta :3");
            } else {
                System.out.println("La expresion no esta escrita de 
     manera correcta :(");
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo con pilas? Quiero decir, sería mucho más sencillo recorrer el string con la operación completa e ir contando paréntesis que abren y los que cierran. Con esto ya lo tendrías

Comment: a fuercitas con pilas :( @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: `x.equals(y)` se lee mucho mejor que `x.compareTo(y) == 0`. Y hacer un bucle haciendo `pop` de una lista en cada iteración se lee mejor con `while (!pila3.isEmpty()) {`

Comment: Cuando dices `input: ((n` ¿en cuántas líneas lo introduces, exactamente?

Comment: En algún momento te dice : **La expresión no esta escrita de manera correcta**?? Viendo la comparación creo que no funcionará

Comment: @SJuan76 en 3 líneas, es decir primero `(` luego enter luego `(` luego enter y luego `n`, o cualquier otra letra.

Comment: @Edu3D no, con ningun ejemplo dio como output **La expresión no está escrita de manera correcta**

Comment: A primera vista no veo nada incorrecto, un par de sugerencias: 1) En tu pregunta muestras 3 comprobaciones distintas. Céntrate en la que da el problema (la que debería mostrar el mensaje de error pero no lo muestra). Eso hace todo lo demás **mucho** más fácil. 2) Depurador o, en su defecto, `System.out.println`. Haz una traza de lo que está haciendo el programa y detecta dónde no se comporta como debería (¿no entra en algún bucle, o hace menos iteraciones de las que tocan?). 3) Revisa el concepto. Igual que la respuesta de Edu3D, tu enfoque no detectará fallo en casos como `)(`.

Answer (score 2):

El método fila.pop() te está devolviendo el primer elemento de la pila, por ejemplo si has introducido **((T** te estará devolviendo el mismo valor y a su vez lo está removiendo de la pila:

```
pila.push("((t");
String devuelvo = pila.pop(); // <-- Este String contendrá ((t
pila.isEmpty(); // <-- TRUE
```

Si haces `pila.pop().equals(")")` te estará devolviendo *false* por ello nunca entrará dentro del **if**

> **NOTA: El método pila.pop() remueve el primer valor de la pila. y el método pila.push() te almacena el valor en la primera posición de la pila**

---

> **EDITADO: se ha usado las pilas para comprobar si es correcto o no.**

```
public class Tarea5sep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("De que tamaño sera su expresion?");
    int n = x.nextInt();

    LinkedList<String> expresiones = new LinkedList<>();

    LinkedList<String> expresionErronea =  new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca su elemento");
        String e = x.next();
        expresiones.push(e);
    }
    x.close();

    // MIENTRAS LA PILA CONTENGA EXPRESIONES...
    while (!expresiones.isEmpty()) {
        expresionErronea.clear();
        String expresion = expresiones.pop();

        // VERIFICAMOS QUE LOS PARENTESIS ESTÁN ABIERTOS Y CERRADOS EN ORDEN
        for (int i = 0; i<expresion.length();i++){
            if (expresion.charAt(i) == '('){ // SI SE ENCUENTRA UN PARENTESIS DE APERTURA
                expresionErronea.push(String.valueOf(expresion.charAt(i))); // SE INTRODUCE EN LA PILA PARA SU VERIFICACIÓN DE CIERRE POSTERIOR.
            } else if (expresion.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if (!expresionErronea.isEmpty()) // SI LA PILA CONTIENE ELEMENTOS
                    expresionErronea.pop(); // SE RETIRAN DE LA MISMA PUES SE HA ENCONTRADO SU CIERRE.
                else // SI LA PILA ESTÁ VACIA SE ESTÁ CERRANDO UN PARENTESIS SIN SU APERTURA. 
                    expresionErronea.push(String.valueOf(expresion.charAt(i)));                 
            }
        }

        if (expresionErronea.isEmpty()){                                
            // VERIFICAMOS QUE LOS SÍMBOLOS ESTÁN CORRECTAMENTE POSICIONADOS
            for (int i = 0; i<expresion.length();i++){
                if (expresion.charAt(i) == ')'){
                    // VERIFICAMOS QUE LOS SIMBOLOS ESTÁN PUESTOS DE FORMA CORRECTA
                    if (expresion.charAt(i-1) == '+' || expresion.charAt(i-1) == '-' || expresion.charAt(i-1) == '*' || expresion.charAt(i-1) == '/' || expresion.charAt(i-1) == '%') {
                        expresionErronea.push(expresion.charAt(i-1)+"");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (expresionErronea.isEmpty()){
                // VERIFICAMOS QUE NO POSEE DOS SIMBOLOS SEGUIDOS O QUE NO ACABE CON UNO SIMBOLO O EMPIEZE CON ALGUN SIMBOLO ERRONEO
                if (expresion.matches("(.*[\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\%]{2,99}.*)") || expresion.matches(".*[\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\%]$") || expresion.matches("^[|\\*|\\/|\\%]"))
                    System.out.println("La expresion NO esta escrita de manera correcta: {"+ expresion + "}");
                else                    
                    System.out.println("La expresion esta escrita de manera correcta: {"+ expresion + "}");
            }else
                System.out.println("La expresion NO esta escrita de manera correcta: {"+ expresion + "}");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("La expresion NO esta escrita de manera correcta: {"+ expresion + "}");
        }
    }
}
```

Quedan varias expresiones por validar, por ejemplo: Si introducimos **3*2+2(t)** esta expresión la contaría como válida

Comment: El problema es que este código reconoce `)(` como una expresión válida; se limita a contar el número de paréntesis abiertos y cerrados. Y estoy prácticamente seguro que no es lo que se pide en el ejercicio (metes los ítems en una pila, pero realmente lo que haces es una iteración normal y corriente).

Comment: Efectivamente, no me había percatado de ese error @SJuan76. Voy a editar mi respuesta usando las pilas ( creo )